# Creating 'fun' storyboard animations?

Tags: silverlight, animation, scrollbar, interpolation

I'm currently using storyboarding like this:

```
 DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation( );
 doubleAnimation.From = _ScrollBar.Value;
 doubleAnimation.To = _Shift;
 doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration( new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 0, 200 ) );

 Storyboard.SetTarget( doubleAnimation, _ScrollBar );
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty( doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath( RangeBase.ValueProperty ) );

 storyboard.Children.Add( doubleAnimation );
 storyboard.Begin( );
```

Which linearly scrolls a scrollbar. Now I was wondering if there's any quick'n'easy ways to make the animation fun (i.e. none linear). Maybe something like a wobble effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at [EasingFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.easingfunction.aspx) that are a part of animations. These allow you to specify an effect (there are a bunch of pre-canned ones to choose from), and it will apply a formula to your linear value change, thus 'wobbling' it up a bit.

References:

- [Add easing effects on your animations with WPF 4 easing functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maximelamure/archive/2009/11/10/add-easing-effects-on-your-animations-with-wpf-4-easing-functions.aspx)
- [Easing Animation with WPF and Silverlight](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2010/03/easing-animation-with-wpf-and-silverlight.html)
- [Easing Functions in WPF 4 (and Silverlight)](http://10rem.net/blog/2009/10/27/easing-functions-in-wpf-4-and-silverlight)

Don't make the basic mistake of going overboard with these though - you don't want to annoy the crap out of the user :)
Now that you know what you are looking for, you will also find that there are a bunch of [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=easing%20%5Bwpf%5D) here on SO about this sort of thing which you can check through.